# How to detect when a HTML5 <video> is played for the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

This will fire the alert each time the play button is clicked. So it will be fired the first time the video is played but also on subsequent plays and if the user pauses then then plays again:

```
$('video').bind('play', function() {
   alert('I have been played!');
});
```

I need to fire an event only once when the video is played for the first time. How can this be done?

Perhaps the jquery one function can be combined with this to make it happen?

Comment: As you suggested, you could just use the `.one()` method, which will automatically unbind the event handler after it's been executed once.

Comment: You have the answer, you can use the `one` method.

Comment: @undefined you're right, should have tried it before posting. It works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('video').one('play', function () {
   //whatever you want to do
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#video_id').one('play', function () {
       //code here
    });
});
```